# how to reorder row position using select statement in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM TJU.`group`;
```

---

```
 group_id, name
      '1', 'x'
      '2', 'y'
      '3', 'z'
      '4', 'a'
      '5', 'b'
```

I want re arrange position of data in `mysql` using select statement

expect output

```
group_id, name
     '1', 'x'
     '2', 'y'
     '3', 'z'
     '5', 'b'
     '4', 'a'
```

please suggest me how to implement this so that I can get record like this

Comment: Is there any business rules behind this requirement?

Comment: You want only select in a new order by  or  you want excahnge the group_id between a and b name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try a query like this:

```
select * from TJU.`group` order by FIELD(group_id,1,2,3,5,4(;;
```

**to change id without name**

```
select 
find_in_set (id,'1,2,3,5,4'),`name`
from TJU.`group`
```

Comment: looking to the question seems that the OP want exchange  the group_id value for a and b name , not  change the order by

Comment: @scaisEdge - ups sorry, my mistake